# Android Studio NDK Build command failed (Missing c Compiler?)

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have tried several days installing the NDK into Android Studio but it always gives me an error message saying that the build failed and I should install a c compiler. I installed the NDK via the SDK Manager by checking the NDK and C Make.

I have already tried completely reinstalling Android Studio and the NDK but that did not work as well -same error.
Something maybe worth mentioning is that if I do not check the C++ support during the project creation there are no errors(but no c++ support too:D).

What should I do because it kills my workflow?

Thank you very much

The Error Message:

> Blockquote
>   External Native Build Issues
>       Build command failed.
>       Error while executing process C:\Users\Julius Debus\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {-HC:\Users\Julius Debus\Desktop\MyApplication\app -BC:\Users\Julius Debus\Desktop\MyApplication\app.externalNativeBuild\cmake\release\armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21 -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Julius Debus\Desktop\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\cmake\release\obj\armeabi-v7a -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\Julius Debus\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\Julius Debus\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Users\Julius Debus\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\ninja.exe -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja}
>       -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/Julius Debus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe
>       -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/Julius Debus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe -- broken
>         It fails with the following output:
>          Change Dir: C:/Users/Julius Debus/Desktop/MyApplication/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/armeabi-v7a/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>         Run Build Command:"C:/Users/Julius
>         Debus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/ninja.exe"
>         "cmTC_a4b3d"
>         [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_a4b3d.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
>         FAILED:
>         C:\Users\JULIUS~1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\NDK-BU~1\TOOLCH~1\llvm\prebuilt\WINDOW~1\bin\clang.exe
>         --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi --gcc-toolchain="C:/Users/Julius
>         Debus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64"
>         --sysroot="C:/Users/Julius
>         Debus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot" -isystem
>         C:/Users/Julius
>         Debus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi
>         -D__ANDROID_API__=21 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables
>         -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a
>         -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -fno-integrated-as -mthumb
>         -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIE -o
>         CMakeFiles/cmTC_a4b3d.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c "C:\Users\Julius
>         Debus\Desktop\MyApplication\app.externalNativeBuild\cmake\release\armeabi-v7a\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c"
>       Error:Error:error: no such file or directory:
>         'Debus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi'

```
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/Julius Debus/Desktop/MyApplication/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/armeabi-v7a/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/Julius Debus/Desktop/MyApplication/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/armeabi-v7a/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\Julius Debus\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {-HC:\Users\Julius Debus\Desktop\MyApplication\app -BC:\Users\Julius Debus\Desktop\MyApplication\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21 -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Julius Debus\Desktop\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\armeabi-v7a -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\Julius Debus\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\Julius Debus\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Users\Julius Debus\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\ninja.exe -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja}
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/Julius Debus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/Julius Debus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe -- broken
  It fails with the following output:
   Change Dir: C:/Users/Julius Debus/Desktop/MyApplication/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
  Run Build Command:"C:/Users/Julius
  Debus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/ninja.exe"
  "cmTC_82ebe"
  [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_82ebe.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
  FAILED:
  C:\Users\JULIUS~1\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\NDK-BU~1\TOOLCH~1\llvm\prebuilt\WINDOW~1\bin\clang.exe
  --target=armv7-none-linux-androideabi --gcc-toolchain="C:/Users/Julius
  Debus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64"
  --sysroot="C:/Users/Julius
  Debus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot" -isystem
  C:/Users/Julius
  Debus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi
  -D__ANDROID_API__=21 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables
  -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv7-a
  -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -fno-integrated-as -mthumb
  -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIE -o
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_82ebe.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c "C:\Users\Julius
  Debus\Desktop\MyApplication\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c"
Error:Error:error: no such file or directory:
  'Debus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi'

  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/Julius Debus/Desktop/MyApplication/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/Julius Debus/Desktop/MyApplication/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

C:\Users\Julius Debus\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake
    Warning:Warning:line (63) (include)   CMakeLists.txt 
    Warning:Warning:line (63) (include)   CMakeLists.txt 
C:\Users\Julius Debus\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\share\cmake-3.6\Modules\CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake
    Error:Error:line (61)/Users/Julius   Debus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe"   is not able to compile a simple test program. 
Open File
    Error:Error:line (61)/Users/Julius   Debus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe"   is not able to compile a simple test program. 
Open File

Comment: `no such file or directory:
  'Debus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi'`  Try using a path that doesn't contain any spaces.

Comment: Thank you very much everything workes fine now :D

Comment: @JuliusDebus Please tell me how can I avoid this issue ? It seems I have the same problem since the user home name contains space, how can I resolve this please?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JuliusDebus
Error while executing process C:\Users\DELL E7440\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments ...

Comment: @JuliusDebus So it gives me the error: ARM-LI~3.EXE: error:


  E7440/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi:


  No such file or directory

Comment: That was some time ago... I'm relatively sure that I either copied the ndk files into a new directory or renamed the existing one. Im not home right now. If you want further explanations just ask again and i'll help you with it.
As i remember it, it was a really simple hack, we should be able to reproduce  that... ;D

Comment: Ok so I've looked up how I had done it: Go to your SDK Manager. It launches into the "Android SDK" tab(shown at the left site). Then you should see a box says "Android SDK Location" enter the path of your directory. Dont forget to create the directory before you enter the path. Also dont forget to include the name of the directory in the path. Then enter your path. In order to avoid acces denial problems and the mentioned Whitespace problems I would just create a directory directly in your root directory like C:\ in Windows. Thats about every advice I can give you. I hope it helps you out. :D